# Ignore woocommerce_product_image_upload_error and save product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

An external application connects to a Woocommerce REST API to add products.
I have control over the woocommerce but not over the application calling the API (the fix must be done in woocommerce, not in the app).
In some cases this app sends products where the image not exist (404) so the REST API returns

```
{
"code": "woocommerce_product_image_upload_error",
"message": "Error recuperando la imagen remota http://xxxxxx.co/20.jpg. Error: Not Found",
"data": {
"status": 400
}
}
```

The endpoint is `https://aaaaaaaaa.ar/wp-json/wc/v2/products/`

I need to ignore this errors and save the products with the default image.

Comment: Could you please show your rest point?

Comment: @Dmitry edited the original post

Comment: Maybe I can extend WC_REST_Products_Controller and override set_product_images but I dont know if this is possible

Comment: I think you need check Woocommerce hooks.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer:

```
function filter_woocommerce_rest_suppress_image_upload_error( $false, $upload, $product_get_id, $images ) { 
    return true;
}; 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_suppress_image_upload_error', 'filter_woocommerce_rest_suppress_image_upload_error', 10, 4 );
```

With this if the image is broken (not found, 404) the product is created with the woocommerce default image, no errors.